# Body Expression in OCL

Tags: ocl

I am new to OCL, and I just came across this expression:

```
context Person::descendants(): Set  
 body: result = self.children -> union(
 self.children -> collect(c | c.descendants()))
```

I now that it's trying to obtain the direct and indirect descendants of a person, but how is that written here, what each sentence is trying to say?

Also this one,

```
context Person::income(): Integer  
body: self.job.salary -> sum()
```

Is this recursive?

Answer (score 0):

result = 
is gratuitous fluff to convert an OCL query into the narrow UML requirements for a Boolean valued body condition. IMHO it should be deleted, and some tools may do so for you.

self.children
is the direct children

x->union(y)
combines two sets

c.descendants()
is a recursion invocation of the descendants()

self.children -> collect(c | c.descendants())
is the recursion applied to each child and with the result accumulated as a Bag

---

There is now a closure() iteration so I would write

context Person::descendants(): Set(Person)
 body: children->closure(children)

Regards

Ed Willink